# files manipulation with multiple delimiters

Tags: linux, bash

I have a paritcular txt file as input, in which there are different type of delimiters (`"one or more blanck space"`,`|`and`|||`). I would like to replace all this delimiters with `,` and delete in the input all `()`. Below an example of input and exptected output.

input.txt

```
Rec        Ligand                  Rank      S-Score | MIF (  H    O    N1  CRY  ) | dSolv |  Etot ( ELJint ELJext  Q  ) |  POSI    (Best  Norm)  ???  Pen   | WScore ( Bridge HExp DAOvlp HOvlp ) WScore_PosiNorm | W_ddG ( W_ddH W_dtdS ) DG_Disp-Per  DG-disp  DDG-pert  ???  Col-DispWat  Num-DispWat  Col-DispWat  Num-DispWat  Col-DispWat  Num-DispWat  DispWat ||| POSIapprox POSIapprox_Norm ||| POSIwat
A2a1071_PEP_REC_prep 4a_001                        1  Scores: 92.535 | 0.64 ( 0.98 0.82 0.38 0.77 ) | 0.64 |  0.32 (  0.00  0.16  0.16 ) |  65.42 (  0.00  51.645 ) 51.89 Pen:  0.00 |||  2.43  (  1.67  0.00  0.15  0.62 )  30.287 |  6.559 (  6.555  0.004 ) |  7.155 (  13.760  6.605 ) || -0.387 || (R 1 Y 2 B 0) |||  117.244  77.134 ||  74.52
```

exptected_output.txt

```
Rec,Ligand,Rank,S-Score,MIF,H,O,N1,CRY,dSolv,Etot,ELJint,ELJext,Q,POSI,Best,Norm,???,Pen,WScore,Bridge,HExp,DAOvlp,HOvlp,WScore_PosiNorm,W_ddG,W_ddH,W_dtdS,DG_Disp-Per,DG-disp,DDG-pert,???,Col-DispWat,Num-DispWat,Col-DispWat,Num-DispWat,Col-DispWat,Num-DispWat,POSIapprox,POSIapprox_Norm,POSIwat
A2a1071_PEP_REC_prep,4a_001,1,92.535,0.64,0.98,0.82,0.38,0.77,0.64,0.32,0,0.16,0.16,65.42,0,51.645,51.89,Pen:0,2.43,1.67,0,0.15,0.62,30.287,6.559,6.555,0.004,7.155,13.76,6.605,-0.387,R,1,Y,2,B,0,117.244,77.134,74.52
```

I did that using a iterative script (below), it works, but is there another way to do all with one command?

myscript:

```
cat heading.txt| tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' > 1.txt
cat 1.txt| tr -s '|' ',' > 2.txt
cat 2.txt| tr -s '(' ',' > 3.txt
cat 3.txt| tr -s ')' ',' > exptected_output.txt
```

Comment: The input, the description, the expected output and the script do not match one another. Is `(space)||(space)(space)` in the input four delimiters (per description: `(space)`, `|`, `|`, `(space)(space)`)? or one delimiter (per expected output)? What happened to `Scores:`? *Maybe* you want `tr -s '[:blank:]()|' ','`, but due to the question being inconsistent, I really cannot tell.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  '[:blank:]()|' ',' works thanks! You are right it is a bit confusing, but your suggestion is right. About 'Scores:' should be delete, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain pipes together.

So your command would look like this:

`cat heading.txt| tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' | tr -s '|' ',' | tr -s '(' ',' | tr -s ')' ',' > exptected_output.txt`

But even better, `tr` can replace multiple strings at the same time. so this is a better solution:
`cat heading.txt| tr -s '[:blank:]|()' ',' > exptected_output.txt`

Comment: How can I delete "Scores:" ???

Comment: you could replace `cat` with `sed 's/Score://g'`. This will remove "Score:" from that file, before passing it to `tr`

Comment: Note: `tr  <heading.txt ...` or `sed <heading.txt` is just fine, no `cat` needed.